# Литература по VBA AutoCAD

Tags: книги, vba, autocad

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста литературу по VBA для AutoCAD. Лучше, конечно, самоучитель.. Но вообще все пойдет. Весь e-net облазил, но не нашел ничего путного.. Только какие-то обрывочные сведения. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: в i-netе смотрели ?

Comment: Конечно, смотрел! Написал ведь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://saprdoc.narod.ru/
Руководство программиста по VBA в AutoCAD 2006 (английский язык).

Comment: Спасибо, fancad, эту книгу я уже нашел.. Очень классная, но некоторые вещи не работают на windows 7 x64. Все равно, +1 !

Answer (score 0):

Бесплатные видео-уроки по работе в AutoCAD

http://store.techcourses.ru/ad/152929/